# Running sqlcmd locally - Error Locating Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a SQL script locally using `sqlcmd`, but I keep getting the following response:

> HResult 0xFFFFFFFF, Level 16, State 1
>   SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
>
> Sqlcmd : error : Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
>
> Sqlcmd : error : Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired

I am running the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S Server\DbName -E -i C:\data.sql
```

I have also tried with `127.0.0.1\DbName` and `localhost\DbName`.  Same result.  I have also looked in the configuration manager and made sure Named Pipes and TCP are enabled for SQL Native Client 10.0.

How do I get this script to run?

Comment: Isn't it Server\InstanceName?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try this:

```
sqlcmd -S Server -d DbName -E -i C:\data.sql
```

You need to specify the **server** after the `-S` and the **database** separately, with a `-d` parameter.

If you're using a non-standard/non-default server **instance**, then you need to specify that with the `-S` parameter, e.g. if you're using the default SQL Server **Express** instance, use this:

```
sqlcmd -S Server\SQLEXPRESS -d DbName -E -i C:\data.sql
```

Here, `Server\SQLEXPRESS` is the **server instance** name - not the server+database name!

Comment: This, unfortunately, does not work for me. I wrote a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562982/server-reached-via-ssms-but-not-via-sqlcmd

Answer (score 3):

Check, if service SQL server browser is running. This settings is visible in SQL server configuration manager.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't help me. What helped me with this seemingly bizarre error was going into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, right-clicking the server node → Properties → Security → setting Server authentication to "Windows Authentication mode" (not a mixed form).

Comment: The error isn't bizarre. Looks like you used the wrong authentication mode. The answer that, completely different, problem is to pass the username and password in the command line, *not* change the server's authentication mode. I'd bet the error you got was different too, as this questions error clearly complains about *network* connectivity.